# R class is missing

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. and i installed eclipse Mars. i created "hello world" App. but the there is an error at:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);//R cannot be resolved to a variable
}
```

i did the folowing:
-clean project.

-delete the files in gen folder to be regenerated automatically

-checked the XML files in your resource folders and all has no errors

-right-click on the project->properties->Android to check that i am using the correct API

but unfortunately that did not solve the problem. please let me know how to fix it

Comment: just open `window>>show view>>error logs` and `problems` and see the problem there

Comment: have you used any image file for layouts.if so,there may be some illegal charters in file name.please check.

Answer (score 0):

Check all of the XML files in your resource folders. If there is an error in any of them, the R file cannot be generated.

Comment: i have checked that one already but i just forgot to mention it in my question ..thanks